# Add a "request CW mode" button to the Ask Question page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, community-wiki

Since only moderators have the power to make a new question CW, please add a "request CW mode" button to the Ask Question page, to make it easier for users to request that their questions become CW.

Comment: +1 to this request, though it should really be on meta.SO (ordinary mods here can do nothing about this).

Comment: @Akhil: I have no idea whether or not the current CW setting is a network-wide or a site-specific preference. I do know that at any case Jeff reads here a lot.

Comment: There's nothing the community moderators can do about the content of the Ask Question page. So I'm migrating this to Meta.SO. On the other hand, note that you can always flag your own question for moderator attention with the request to make CW.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, *no*. The checkbox was taken away so people would *stop even thinking about* CW for questions.  See the two bullet points at the bottom of waffles's answer.

Comment: @Aarobot: the CW feature continues to be widely used on Math Overflow.  It is very useful, for instance, as a middle ground between distinctly acceptable and distinctly unacceptable content, as well as for asking questions which probably do not have a single correct answer.  The users at math.SE are missing this feature.  Simply repeating "no" a bunch of times to our request seems obnoxious to me: *in our community, this is a feature we found to be helpful*.

Comment: Having said that, I don't understand why we shouldn't just be asking for the "make this question CW" box to be reinstated, possibly with a modest minimal rep for use.

Comment: @Pete: The use of CW as a designation for borderline questions is *exactly why the feature was taken away*. Nothing but respect for you folks at MO, you should run the site how you see fit - but here on SE we've simply concluded that the feature does more harm than good.  Either a question is acceptable or it's not.  If it's not, close it.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm ... not following how this would be better than this.

[image: flag]

If you feel so strongly that a question you are asking should be CW I think you should ask yourself why.

- Why do you think you deserve no rep for this question?
- Why do you think this question even belongs on the site?

Comment: I would add as the first bullet: Why do you want everybody to be able to edit your question?

Comment: @Aarobot ... I thought about that, but now with the "pending edits" system - this become arcane. "Why would you want low rep users to edit your question without the edit being reviewed?" ... Weird thing to want